# Data recovery from file collections

Tags: forensics, data-recovery

I am presently working as a summer intern.

My first objective is, given a collection of files, recover and identify the file types present in it.

To download sample pseudo-forensics data I have been using: [Digital Corpora](http://digitalcorpora.org/)

To recover files I have been using '[The Sleuthkit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/)' but this does not seem to do the work as I always get error messages regarding the format of the data being used.

It would be great to get suggestions/links to tutorials or software which help in recovering data.

I am also looking forward to links to download psuedo forensic data similar to the one above.

Specifically, I would like to recover all data that are in text formats(word,pdf,emails,html... etc) then unify it into one single file in text format and then use natural language processing to determine places the person was associated with. I have some ideas with respect the natural language processing aspect of the problem but need help with respect to data recovery. How best to do this task.

Comment: What you are asking is FAR too broad for us to answer. You could analyze the file collection using shell scripts, for instance.

Comment: @schroeder could you please guide me towards tutorials or links. Basically given a hard drive i want to recover files to analyze later. Thank you

Comment: Your problem is too undefined to provide tutorials. What do you mean by 'recover'? Are you just indexing the files or do you want some other kind of processing? What kind of 'analysis' do you expect to do 'later'? There is just too many ways you could look at this problem. Refine the problem, then the answers will come.

Comment: @schroeder I would like to recover all data that are in text formats(word,pdf,email,html... etc) then unify it into one single file in text format and then use natural language processing to determine places the person was associated with. How best to do this task.

Thank you

Comment: Update your question with these details, please.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a forensic tool like ftk imager to image the drive and then work from there. I also suggest just buying a book on 'data forensics' to learn the basics.

Comment: @MatthewPeters could you please give me some suggestions regarding books to buy to learn the basics. Thank you

Comment: It's a few years out of date but the principles are still valid. I used: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321268172

Comment: @MatthewPeters yes i have this book will go thru. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question but here is one way you could possibly do it,
you could use autopsy over the full sleuthkit as it is really just a wrapper for the sleuth kit but a heck of a lot easier to use.

Next index your target disk (assuming it is coming from a hard disk) and you can then regex query your index from the autopsy using things like *.doc* or whatever.

Comment: what do you mean by indexing?

Comment: When you load the file with autopsy you let it index the file system which makes it searchable 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing